# Padding inconsistancy in Chrome span tag

Tags: google-chrome, padding, html

I have discovered an inconsistency in the way Chrome adds padding to span tags. When using a simple span tag with a small font-size and a text, the padding above and below is larger than in Internet explorer. When using a large font-size the padding is the same.

This can be tested with the following code/jsfiddle

```
<span>Testing A Text</span>
<span>Testing A Text</span>

body
{    
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,"Sans Serif";
    font-size: 10px;
}
span
{
     border: 1px solid red;   
}
span:last-child
{
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

(Can be previewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/gR9em/5/)

Of course, this can be solved by conditional CSS or using different fonts but that is a thing I would like to avoid if possible. This might be "Arial" -related... However, could anyone explain this and perhaps provide a solution? Or is this a known browser CSS "bug"?

Example with image here:

[image: Preview]

Comment: which version of Internet explorer are you referring to ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the issue is related to padding, but rather line-height.

Example with correct *padding*: http://jsfiddle.net/qh3aY/1/

Ideally you would set up the `line-height` on the `<body>` but I wanted to follow the OPs markup.

IIRC, `<span>` elements should always be inside another element like a `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the jsFiddle again in Chrome and it seems like the padding below the text has disappeared and the padding above the text is less than it was when I posted this issue. Maybe something was updated in Chrome.

I guess the line-height should ideally not work differently between different browsers...